# How to serialize an object

Tags: python, json, numpy

i have a method that does some calculations and must return a dictionary as shown below in the code section.
the method can not return the dictionary as it contains non serialized data.
i tried to enocod it as explained in the link below
https://pynative.com/online-python-code-editor-to-execute-python-code/
and her as well
[TypeError: Object of type 'float32' is not JSON serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53082708/typeerror-object-of-type-float32-is-not-json-serializable)

but i still receive the same error message.
please let me know how to solve this issue

**code**:

```
resultsDict = {
    "pixelsValuesSatisfyThresholdInWindowSegment":json.dumps(numpyData,cls=NumpyArrayEncoder),
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
return resultsDict
```

**error message**

```
raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type float32 is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: Maybe you will find something [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53082708/typeerror-object-of-type-float32-is-not-json-serializable)

Comment: share `NumpyArrayEncoder` and `numpyData `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just did the following

```
resultsDict = 
 {"pixelsValuesSatisfyThresholdInWindowSegment":str(pixelsValuesSatisfyThresholdInWindowSegment)
}
```

and it is working.